# Browser plug-in for JPEGs with zoom

Tags: browser, plugins, jpeg

Does someone know a plug-in that allows me to open JPEG files on my browser (Internet Explorer or Firefox) with zoom and rotation buttons? I have tried to find it but without succes : (

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Flash or Silverlight plugins there are some programming/integration options options: Zoomify (http://www.zoomify.com/) and DeepZoom (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Zoom) respectively.

There is also some javascript or jQuery options (http://www.visual-blast.com/source/jqzoom/)

Answer (score 1):

[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) also could be useful. Could you detail why you want to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Possible in [Javascript](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+image+zoom):

- [5
  zoom scripts discussed](http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/javascript-zoom-scripts/)
- [With
  JQuery](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/27/zoom-in-with-a-jquery-plugin/)
- [etc](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/mojozoom/)

I don't see any advantage to use Applets, Flash or Silverlight.